# How to Design a service that can consume REST endpoints. Need support to add new endpoints at runtime

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-integration, iot, platform

I am trying to create a service that consumes data from different cloud providers and it should be able to support adding new providers at runtime.
To be specific, trying to build to something like this : https://my.artik.cloud/devices

A cloud platform to integrate with various device types. The minimum requirement is able to add new device integration without changing the code. Any pointers on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way from Spring Integration perspective is [Dynamic Integration Flow Registrations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows) and recently fixed mechanism to register REST endpoints at runtime: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4436

So, right: this is not possible right now, but it is going to be as a feature in the next `5.1` version.

Comment: Well, workaround is to copy/paste an `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` from `5.1` to your own project and register it as a `HttpContextUtils.HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME` bean. This way your one will have a precedence over one registered by Framework.